# How to update Thunderbird in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, thunderbird, updates

I have Thunderbird version 3.0.5 and nowadays newer version Thunderbird 3.1 is available.

How can I update my Thunderbird under Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variant 1: use the last daily build. Add ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa to your software sources and install it. If you don't want to get an update every day, remove it again from the sources.

Variant 2, use Ubuntuzilla (you can find that one in the main repository).

Answer (score 3):

You can include the daily-build ppa for mozilla in your sources. Instructions are at https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ppa